# Making Google Cloud image public

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We created a couple custom images on Google Cloud and now would like to make it public. How do we do it?

There are a few articles on how to share with other projects or users within your organizations, but, how do we make it public that all users on Google Cloud can find and use it?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cloud storage CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52264456/cloud-storage-cors)

Comment: Nope, not it. I am looking at sharing public vm images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that is not possible to make your custom image public due to public images in Google Cloud are managed by Google, they are the only ones that can upload or remove public images.

However, your solution could be to create a Marketplace Solution [1][2]. If you create a Marketplace Solution you could share your custom image and everyone can use it.

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/

[2] https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/custom-deployments